# How to disable access to an aws instance using one particular ppk file

Tags: amazon-web-services

I lost the .pem file of an  `AWS suse Linux` instance.The ".ppk" file that was generated  before the loss of .pem file is given to many  people,so now I should either disable the access via that .ppk file or I must set-up  a password prompt even after using that .ppk file. How  can I do this?

The instance cannot be shut-down and restarted  for a new .pem file so please tell me how to set a password for the instance even after using that .ppk file.

Answer (score 1):

If you log on to the instance you can remove the associated public key from the `authorised_keys` file for the related user (such as `ec2-user`). Obviously if you want to be able to login to that instance yourself then you will need to add the public key of a secure private key to one of the authorised_key files.

I'd consider taking this opportunity to think about how, in the future, you can enable yourself to simply rebuild the instance with a new key and zero data loss for incidents such as this.